# why window variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Could you please tell me why `window variable is undefined`.here is my code

```
var name = "jjjjj";
$(function () {
  console.log("-jjjj----");
});
```

I am trying to import this jira dynamically .on console i am cheching `name` value it is undefined.

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-bhaskara-u0lic?file=/pages/index.js).

```
useEffect(() => {
    import("jquery").then((jquery) => {
      console.log("======", jquery);
      window.jQuery = jquery.default;
      window.$ = jquery.default;
      import("../a.js").then((r) => {
        console.log("====", r);
      });
    });
  }, []);
```

I am trying to get `window.name`

Comment: What is your environment? How are you running the code? Are you sure you are running the code in the browser? If you are running in node, there will be no window

Comment: @jhamm on browser only

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the `useEffect` and open your console, what do you see when you run `window.name`? I just ran it in my console and got an empty string. Do you have the `window` object available?

Comment: @jhamm i found the solution .instead of  `var name = "jjjjj";` i need to used like this `window.name='jjjjj'`